# deferred.resolve() won't resolve

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that check for email address in database. The problem is, even if `result` value is `1` or `-1` the form will still submit. Here is the `HTML`:

```
<form name="myForm" target="_self" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<!-- If using a Business or Company Logo Graphic, include the "cpp_header_image" variable. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<!-- Replace "business" value with your PayPal Email Address or your Merchant Account ID -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="webmaster@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="">
<!-- Purpose field -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Your Donation">
<!-- -->

<label>Email Address</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="custom">
<br><br>
<label>Donation</label>
<select name="amount">
<option value="10">USD 10</option>
<option value="30">USD 30</option>
</select>

<br>
<!-- -->

<input id="check_email" type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Donate to!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

`JQuery`

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
//function to check email availability  
var check_email_availability  = function (){

var email_check = $.Deferred();

        //use ajax to run the check
        $.post("/validate_email.php", { email: email },
            function(result){
                //if the result is 1
                if(result == 1){
                    //show that the email does not exist available
                    alert("Email does not exist in db");
                }if(result == 0){
                    //show that the email found in the system                                       
                    email_check.resolve();                  
                }if(result == -1){
                    //show that the email format is invalid                                                                 
                    alert("Email Format invalid");
                }
        });
return email_check;
}  //function end   

    $("#check_email").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
        if($("#email").val() != ""){
            ( check_email_availability()).done($("form[name='myForm']").submit());   
        }
    }); //click event end       
});
```

Form are to suppose to be submitted when `result == 0`. I prefer to use `$.Deferred()` Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a function reference to `.done()` like this:

```
check_email_availability().done(function() {
    $("form[name='myForm']").submit();
});
```

The way you were doing it you were executing the `.submit()` immediately and passing the return value from that to `.done()` which (as you have discovered) is not the timing you want.

You could also change your code to use the promise that `$.post()` returns rather than creating your own like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //function to check email availability  
    function check_email_availability() {
        //use ajax to run the check
        return $.post("/validate_email.php",  { email: email });
    }

    $("#check_email").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($("#email").val()) {
            check_email_availability().then(function(result) {
                if (result === 0) {
                    $("form[name='myForm']").submit();
                } else if (result == 1) {
                    alert("Email does not exist in db");
                } else if (result == -1) {
                    alert("Email Format invalid");
                }
            });
        }
    }); //click event end       
});
```

Comment: Added an alternate way of doing this that uses the promise returned by `$.post()` rather than creating your own.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the form submit in the done callback, in your case you are doing the form submit before the deferred is resolved. ie you are calling form submit first and then is trying to pass the value returned from that as the argument to `done()`

```
check_email_availability().done(function(){
    $("form[name='myForm']").submit()
});
```

Also from `check_email_availability` you should return only a promise object, not the deferred itself like `return email_check.promise();`

Comment: Regarding your comment bottom comment, are you suggesting me to replace `return email_check;` to `return email_check.promise();`?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm asking too much but why does I need to insert the `return email_check.promise();`? The way I understand it, you don't need `promise()` because `resolve()` will inform `done()` that it is done. Anyway if I'm remove `promise()` from the function, my form will not submit. I confuse?? Why does I need it?

Comment: @sg552 because using `deferred` anybody can call methods like `resolve/reject` on the deferred object, but if you return an `promise` then the outside function can only register callbacks like `done/fail/always` etc... then cannot either `resolve/reject`.. so it is a safety feature